# google maps and scopes within greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, google-maps, greasemonkey

I am writing a greasemonkey script that will allow its users to click a button and view a popup map. I am going to try and use google maps for actually creating the map and plotting a few points. I have a couple of questions about this however.
First, would using script to create an iframe within my popup div that calls a script from my server have to use an api key for my server, or would it have to be a key for the site the greasemonkey script will run on?
Secondly, if this fails is there a way to use JS to plot points on an image like image magick does for PHP?

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Google Maps Javascript API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Welcome) you don't need API keys anymore.

To generate images with javascript, you could use the new `<canvas>` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial

Comment: Great! Thanks. I'll have a look.